# Using reflection can I read file contents

Tags: c#, system.reflection

In a class library project, I added a folder named 'READ', I then added a text file('test.txt') in that folder. Using     System.Reflection, is it possible to read test.txt file. 
If I add test.txt file as resource and then add this class library as reference I can access test.txt file. But I would like to know using reflection whether its possible to read the text file.

Comment: Can you describe _why_ you want to use reflection? I don't know whether methods like `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` fall in the reflection category.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yeah, I got my answer It can be done by same http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Answer (score 3):

The System.Reflection API allows your code to do things with .Net types (classes, structs, etc). It does not contain any tools for opening or reading files.

You should be looking at System.IO instead.